# is_array function php to Python

Tags: python, php, arrays, function

I am migrating php code into Python and came across is_array function that I'm having trouble with translating. 
Here is php code:

```
function is_assoc($var)
{
  return is_array($var) && array_diff_key($var, array_keys(array_keys($var)));
}
```

What would be the equivalent of is_array function in Python?

Comment: [`isinstance(var, list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Answer (score 3):

You can remove `set` if you wish:

```
is_array = lambda var: isinstance(var, (list, tuple, set))

a = [1,2,3]
b = (1,2,3)
c = {1,2,3}
print(is_array(a))
print(is_array(b))
print(is_array(c))
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any such `Array` datatype in Python, what you'll probably use in its place is a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

As such you can check if a particular variable is in fact a list using [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
isinstance(var, list);
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@esqew/UnlawfulSphericalTrigger)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method 'type' to check the type of the object:

```
a = [1,2,3]
type(a) == list
```